# Changing images on buttons via other buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

Is there a way to change the image of a button by pressing another button?

I have a Play button that after it is pressed changes the image to Pause and vice versa.

Now, I have a Stop button and I need to set the Play button image to Play again (because it's staying with the Pause button).

Any suggestions on this?

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender 
{
    UIImage *playImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"playFinal" ofType:@"png"]];
    UIImage *pauseImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pauseFinal" ofType:@"png"]];

    if ([self.background isPlaying]) 
    {
        [sender setImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.background pause];
    }
    else 
    {
        [sender setImage:pauseImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.background play]; 
    }
}

- (IBAction)stop 
{
    UIImage *playImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"playFinal" ofType:@"png"]];

    // What has to be done here?

    [self.background stop];
    [self.background setCurrentTime:0];
}
```

Comment: Should be possible by modifying the inner HTML. Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: I think code is useless in this case. I described my situation a little bit clearer in the main post.

Comment: The reason I asked is that in order to modify the inner HTML, we need to know what is already there. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Code is now in the main post.

Comment: Sorry man. No idea about this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an outlet to your button like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
```

connect it to your button in interface builder and then:

```
[playButton setImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.background stop];
...
```

Comment: Well, that actually worked! Big ups to you, sir! Never thought of such a way :)